# What is the use of Package.appxmanifest.xml file in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have created a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project from Visual Studio 2013. The project has two different manifest files WMAppManifest.xml and Package.appxmanifest.xml. 
All information like Display Name, Initial Navigation Page, Notification Service, Tile  Title, Version number etc... goes into my WMAppManifest.xml file. I never use the other manifest file. Even when I extract the "xap" of my application, it only contains the WMAppManifest.xml. 
So then what is the use of Package.appxmanifest.xml in Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight application?

Answer (score 1):

It is used for certain scenarios involving WinRT APIs and features. For example, things like adding universal [Background Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh977056.aspx) and some WinRT APIs require capabilities defined in the AppX manifest rather than the WMAppManifest.

Comment: But if I target my application to windows phone silverlight 8.1, I will be unable to use WinRT APIs. So I don't need Appx manifest?

Comment: That's not the case. Many (but not all) WinRT APIs are available to Silverlight 8.1 apps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually hand edit certain values in the Package.appxmanifest.xml file. 
See this link: [Prepare your Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 app for publishing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Dn655122(v=VS.105).aspx)

Comment: If I am uploading a xap file to the store, then why do I need to make changes to  Package.appxmanifest.xml? Bcz anyway the xap doesn't contain that  file.